# Cropping a QImage using Mouse Events in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv3.0, qimage

I need to crop a QImage displayed on a QLabel. I want to do it with mouseevents like dragging a rectangle on the image and then on the releaseevent the image should crop to the size of the rectangle. I have implemented this code:

```
void surf_detection::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
if(ui->label_2->underMouse()){
    cout <<"Entered Press"<<endl;
    origin = ev->pos();
    //if (!rubberBand)
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);

        rubberBand->show();
}
}

void surf_detection::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{

rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, ev->pos()).normalized());                                                                                                              
}

void surf_detection::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev)
{
QPoint a = mapToGlobal(origin);
QPoint b = ev->globalPos();

a = ui->label_2->mapFromGlobal(a);
b = ui->label_2->mapFromGlobal(b);
rubberBand->hide();
QPixmap OriginalPix(*ui->label_2->pixmap());
double sx = ui->label_2->rect().width();
double sy = ui->label_2->rect().height();
sx = OriginalPix.width() / sx;
sy = OriginalPix.height() / sy;

a.x = int(a.x * sx);
b.x = int(b.x * sx);
a.y = int(a.y * sy);
b.y = int(b.y * sy);

QRect myRect(a,b);

QImage newImage;
newImage = OriginalPix.toImage();

QImage copyImage;
copyImage = copyImage.copy(myRect);

ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(copyImage));
ui->label_2->repaint();

}
```

But this code gives me error at

```
a.x = int(a.x * sx);
b.x = int(b.x * sx);
a.y = int(a.y * sy);
b.y = int(b.y * sy);
```

error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)

a.x = int(a.x * sx);
                  ^

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

By listening to your compiler :

```
a.setX(int(a.x() * sx));
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But now after drawing rectangle the image simply disappears from the QLabel. I don't understand where am i going wrong.

Comment: Have you already solved this disappearance? I am also getting this in my program.